# How one reads data from memory pointer sequentially, element after element?

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory, delphi-7

I want to use a function from FMOD library that locks data in memory of a given sound and returns pointer to the data, so some reading or modification of the data can be done:

```
function FSOUND_Sample_Lock(Sptr: PFSoundSample; Offset: Integer; Length: Integer; 
        var Ptr1: Pointer; var Ptr2: Pointer; var Len1: Cardinal; 
        var Len2: Cardinal): ByteBool;
```

ptr1 and ptr2 is a pointer to memory,  len1 and len2 is length of the data in the memory.

How can I iterate over the data at ptr1 reading each time next SmallInt ?

I'm using Delphi 7 so {$POINTERMATH ON} does not work

Comment: Cast `Ptr1` to a `PSmallInt` variable. Then use `Inc` which will increment the pointer by the size of a smallint each time.

Comment: Read: Pointer Math aka http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)

Comment: @DavidM that is the answer, not the comment :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Feel free to answer it using that. I haven't got Delphi here atm!

Comment: @davidm neither do I,  not d7 at least

Comment: TopicStarter: next time please put Delphi version tag from beginning. Now try `var ps: ^SmallInt; PS := ptr1; I := ps^; Inc(ps); j := ps^; PS := Succ(ps) ; k := ps^;` and so on.  This pointer math AFAIR is part of original 1974 Pascal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a modern Delphi, with [`{$POINTERMATH ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_%28Delphi%29), you can index the elements of the array like this:

```
PSmallint(ptr1)[i]
```

If you don't have `$POINTERMATH` in your Delphi, or if you prefer to leave it off, you can do this:

```
type
  TSmallintArray = array[0..MaxInt div SizeOf(Smallint)-1] of Smallint;
  PSmallintArray = ^TSmallintArray;
```

And then access the elements with:

```
PSmallintArray(ptr1)[i]
```

Personally I've never found the latter approach to my tastes, but the choice is yours.

Comment: Version-agnostic way is casting to `PSmallIntArray`

Comment: the second option works well. I cannot use the first one as I'm using old delphi version. thank you